# Error defaultConsequence(Lorg/drools/core/spi/KnowledgeHelper;)V

Tags: drools

I am trying to clone a rule, overwriting `agenda-group` in Java using the `RuleImpl` class. While creating the rule I'm setting the rule LHS and consequence values like this:

```
RuleImpl newRuleImpl = new RuleImpl("conseq-scenario-new");
newRuleImpl.setAgendaGroup("conseq1");
newRuleImpl.setLhs(tempRule.getLhs());
newRuleImpl.setConsequence(tempRule.getConsequence());
```

"tempRule" is the rule picked from container:

```
rule "conseq-scenario-mars"
agenda-group "conseq"
when
    addr: Address(postcode == "12345")
then
    addr.setStreet("TEST STREET");
end
```

Now when I am trying to access the rule, I am getting the below exception:

```
at runtime: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
 rules.Rule_conseq$u45$scenario$u45$mars1006137205.defaultConsequence(Lorg/drools/core/spi/KnowledgeHelper;)V
    at rules.Rule_conseq$u45$scenario$u45$mars1006137205DefaultConsequenceInvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown
 Source)
    at rules.Rule_conseq$u45$scenario$u45$mars1006137205DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I've fixed your formatting -- please use code blocks for code, not quote blocks.

Comment: What version of Drools are you using?

Comment: Thanks for formatting. I am using 7.59 final version